# Trouble passing string to lpctstr in WinCE5 API call

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, smart-device

I am trying to make a call to the Windows CE 5 API call, "[FindFirstChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889670.aspx)" in a VS2008 Smart Device project using:

```
Private Declare Function FindFirstChangeNotification Lib "coredll.dll" _
(ByVal lpPathName As String, ByVal bWatchSubtree As Long, _
ByVal dwNotifyFilter As Long) As Long

Dim strFolderPath As String = "\My Documents\My App Files\"
Dim ptrHandle as IntPtr = FindFirstChangeNotification(strFolderPath, 0, 1)
```

Attempting this method results in a "System.NotSupportedException" which I assume to be an incompatibility in string types.  Despite attempting different marshaling behaviors I'm still stuck after several days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String types in Windows CE are Unicode, so declaring as `String` should be correct.

Coredll actually exports the function as `FindFirstChangeNotificationW` (note trailing 'W'), so that is likely the reason you're getting an exception.

'W' indicates a Wide, as in wide-character or Unicode, implementation of the function. Generally you can use the `dumpbin` tool in a Visual Studio command prompt to identify the names of function exports, in this case I used `dumpbin /exports coredll.dll` to check.

Also, as far as I know, in VB.Net `Long` is a 64-bit type, and `FindFirstChangeNotification` expects 32-bit arguments.

So try this:

```
Private Declare Function FindFirstChangeNotificationW Lib "coredll.dll" _
(ByVal lpPathName As String, ByVal bWatchSubtree As Integer, _
ByVal dwNotifyFilter As Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That was the issue.